# `which`, `gcc` not behaving as expected

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, llvm-gcc

I have a nearly fresh mac High Sierra installation. I installed gcc 4.9 with homebrew, and now I want to make sure that's the default gcc (not clang). So I typed the following commands and got the following outputs. And they make no sense to me. Shouldn't `gcc -v` and `gcc-4.9 -v` have the same outputs? Why are they different? It seems to me that I don't understand how `which` works or how symlinks work, which is a surprise because I thought I did.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
$ ls -l $(which gcc)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  22 Mar  1 09:50 /usr/local/bin/gcc -> /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
$ which gcc-4.9
/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
$ gcc-4.9 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/4.9.4/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/lib/gcc/4.9 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --enable-plugin --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 4.9.4_1' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues MAKEINFO=missing --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.4 (Homebrew GCC 4.9.4_1) 
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

For context, I'm loosely following these instructions https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/DEVELOPMENT-OSX-NATIVE.md#os-x-development-tools . I don't think it really matters, but I'm including it for context's sake.

Comment: Maybe you have set up an alias. Try `type gcc` and `type gcc-4.9`

Comment: `$ type gcc`

`gcc is /usr/local/bin/gcc`

`$ type gcc-4.9`
`gcc-4.9 is /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`

I didn't think I'd set up an alias.

Comment: So `gcc` is a symlink to `gcc-4.9` but you get different output if you run `gcc -v` from if you run `gcc-4.9 -v`? That's mad. Try rehashing with `hash -r` then try again.

Comment: Yeah, it is mad! But that totally fixed it. I learned about `hash` today, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell environment was remembering the previous locations of the commands. Using `hash -r` makes the shell forget them, so now everything behaves as expected.

Thanks to Mark Setchell in the comments above.